# Convert Group of Picture structure to the appropriate one for HEVC HM encoder

Tags: encoding, hevc

I'm using `HM-16` and `Scalable HM 12.3`.

I have this GOP order as seen below.  As you can see I have QP value for each slice type.

```
Encode Order     Type    POC     QP
0    I-SLICE    0   23
1    P-SLICE    3   26
2    B-SLICE    2   27
3    b-SLICE    1   28
4    P-SLICE    6   26
5    B-SLICE    5   27
6    b-SLICE    4   28
```

And I want to convert it to a code like the following where I must define `QPoffset CbQPoffset CrQPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2 temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures     predict deltaRPS #ref_idcs reference idcs`.

```
#        Type POC QPoffset CbQPoffset CrQPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2 temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures     predict deltaRPS #ref_idcs reference idcs 
Frame1:  P   16   1        0          0          0.6      0            0              0           2                3         -16 -24 -32            0
Frame2:  B    8   2        0          0          0.2      0            0              1           2                3         -8  -16   8            1       8        4         1 1 0 1
```

Can you please help me to convert it?

Is there any other way to define the number of B-frames or b-frames in a GOP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution considering [HM reference manual](https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/trunk/doc/software-manual.pdf).

I reorder the frames starting from a `B-frame` considering only one reference frame. All B frames reference previous `I-frame` or `P-frames`.

The new GOP structure is the one below.

It's important to mention here, that a `B-frame` can't have a `P-frame` that is encoded later. More explicitly, a `B-frame` with POC number e.g. 1 can't reference a `P-frame` with a grater value of POC number e.g. 3.

```
#        Type POC QPoffset CbQPoffset CrQPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2 temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures     predict deltaRPS #ref_idcs reference idcs 
Frame1:  B    1   2        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -1                    0      
Frame2:  B    2   1        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -2                    2     1      
Frame3:  P    3   0        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -3                    2     2 
Frame4:  B    4   2        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -1                    2     2           
Frame5:  B    5   1        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -2                    2     3            
Frame6:  P    6   0        0          0          0.4624    0            0               0           1                1         -3                    2     3
```